# Remote administration between 2 host behind different NAT

Tags: networking, router, ssh, nat

I have 2 computers, both connect to the internet using different routers in different locations, therefore not having a fixed public IP address.

Computer A is the admin Pc and needs to get a shell on computer B.
Computer A forwards his connections through a ssh tunnel to a router with static IP, the tunnel is created with:

```
ssh -D 2022 username@<routerstaticIp> -p 22
```

Computer B can't ssh into the router.
This way the admin can secure his connections when connects from randoms WiFi and also have the same static public IP.

How computer B can send a reverse shell to computer A knowing `<routerstaticIp>`?
Both computers uses Debian.
I would like to have some advice before tampering with port forwarding or iptables, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computer B needs to have SSH access to the same system, creating a "remote" tunnel using `-R`:

```
ssh -R 9999:localhost:22 username@ROUTER
```

With this, other computers can ssh into the router and from there into localhost:9999, which the router's SSH server will relay to localhost:22 of computer B.

(For example, computer A could `ssh -J username@ROUTER -p 9999 localhost`.)

Comment: My bad, I forgot to specify that computer B does not have the credentials to ssh into the router, I'll edit the question.

Comment: But gave me to think, maybe from computer A can be created reverse tunnel with 'ssh -R <routerport>' and computer B can send a shell to <routerstaticIp>:<routerport> ??